# PHP mail() no longer works after update to OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: php, email, xampp, osx-mountain-lion

I just updated OS X to Mountain Lion yesterday, but the php function `mail()` does not work anymore.

Before updating, the PHP `mail()` function worked fine, Apple mail works fine.
After updating, Apple mail works fine, but PHP `mail()` function DOES NOT work.

Webserver: XAMPP 1.7.3

I use this code to test the `mail()` function:

```
if (mail($to, $object, $content, "From: ". $from)) 
{ 
    echo 'send '; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "not send"; 
}
```

It shows: `not send`

Anything I have to change? such as the `php.ini` or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `sendmail_path` in `php.ini` and make sure that you have `sendmail` installed on your system and that the path matches PHP.  Then check your syslog or logs directory for any errors from the mail server.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
After looking at the error_log (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log), there is an error:
**sendmail: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory**

Do the following at your terminal:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

Then the php mail() works!

Reference:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/sendmail-error-on-os-x-mountain-lion

Comment: I got some errors on the terminal commands regarding postfix, but your solution worked!

Comment: Fix worked for me, though I did get a few odd warnings at the terminal as well. In the end, it worked though!

Comment: here's instructions how to load sendmail at startup: http://remonpel.nl/2013/03/sending-mail-from-php-with-mountain-lion/

Comment: This [alternative answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105802) from that thread also works (point the configuration where postfix actually resides). The `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool` folder is how OS X Server handles things. The postfix default is `/var/spool/postfix` and already existed on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

After creating the spool folder as described above, I configured postfix following the directions on this article [OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081217161612647)

I also had to edit my php.ini sendmail path to have some extra switches, specifically

```
sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```