# Step-by-step guide to make PHP's mail() function work on OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, email, osx-mavericks

Since I've updated to Mavericks the [`mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function doesn't work anymore.

```
mail('mail@example.com', 'subject', 'message')
```

returns **true** but no email is in my inbox

Is there a **step-by-step guide** to get this work? I've limited knowledge with postfix, smtp, sendmail and that stuff so please be nice

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check spam box?

Comment: sure, I've tested with an email without spam protection and the email does not arrive

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Moutain Lion whenever I restarted and this helped:

[PHP mail() no longer works after update to OSX Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696609/php-mail-no-longer-works-after-update-to-osx-mountain-lion)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work either. I get a "the Postfix mail system is already running" - "error" though but no mail is sent