# How to test PHP mail() function on OSX Mavericks?

Tags: php, email, osx-mavericks

I had `mail()` function working locally before the update to OSX Mavericks. It seems like it's a common issue, but I haven't found any working solution so far.

PHP `mail()` returns `true`, but nothing is being sent. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Step-by-step guide to make PHP's mail() function work on OS X Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541445/step-by-step-guide-to-make-phps-mail-function-work-on-os-x-mavericks)

Comment: Unfortunetely it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I installed Postfix e-mail service for sending e-mail on my Mac.  I'm running Mavericks (OS X 10.9.2) from web applications or command line, but had set this up on Mountain Lion originally.  If I understand correctly, the sendmail binary will look for an available service to send through which is why you need Postfix running.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix set-permissions
sudo /usr/sbin/postfix start
```

To test just run these commands.

```
sendmail user@domain.com 'my subject line'
type whatever you want to write

then press ctrl-d to send
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for answer! But, how does this answer connect to PHP? Once Postfix is setup, does one need to edit `php.ini` or do anything else special to get it to work? Thanks!

Comment: PHP looks for sendmail on your system.  You shouldn't need to edit your php.ini file.  Did you try the answer above and attempt to use the PHP mail function to send a message?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Darryl! **Re:** `Did you try the answer above and attempt to use the PHP mail function to send a message?`; **A:** That's what I want to do. I have not tried yet due to so many solutions floating around. Noob question, do I need to start postfix everytime I want to test mail sending?

Comment: I believe when sendmail, which the php mail function uses, is executed it starts postfix if it's not already running as a service.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Darryl! +1. As an update, I tried your solution, and it worked, to an extent. The mail I sent got caught in my `/var/mail/<user>` dir; running `cat /var/mail/<user>` showed me the message and that it "failed" to send. _All I want for Christmas is an **easy** way to let XAMPP, and PHP's `mail()`, send e-mails to an address of my choice (on OS X Mavericks)._ Any possibility you could provide the PHP portion of this code, say, to send an e-mail to a gmail inbox? Either way, if I figure it out, I'll post an answer too. Thanks again! :)

Comment: A few questions.  (1) Are you running the built-in PHP that comes installed on OS X?  (2) Did you run at the command line: sendmail whoever@whateverDomain.com 'some subject line' and enter a message ending the input with ctrl-d or did you just try to send via PHP?  You need to ensure this is working before attempting to send via PHP.  (3) after you run the sendmail command, run sudo /usr/sbin/postfix status; does it show that postfix is running?  (4) During the postfix install did you receive any error messages?

Comment: Darryl! Thanks! (1) No, XAMPP (so that could be the problem). (2) Yes. That didn't work as I got a message send failure (I probably need to re-check and re-test my settings). (3) Thanks for tip! I did not check that, I will now though. (4) No errors. | Thanks for all of your help. In the end, I may just slap my code on my host's box and go from there (or use [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)). Thanks again!

Comment: sorry I couldn't help you through this.  I'm certainly not an expert in postfix and sendmail, I just posted what worked for me.

Comment: Oh, no worries at all Darryl! +100 for all your help and advice! It's much appreciated. :)